# Doing wire 3D cube without libraries

Tags: java, matrix, reinventing-the-wheel, graphics

I was having fun implementing some really basic stuff for 3D graphics. See what I came up with:

**Matrix.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.lib3d;

/**
 * This class represents a matrix.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Matrix {

    /**
     * The actual elements.
     */
    private final double[][] matrix;

    /**
     * Constructs a zero matrix with <code>rows</code> rows and
     * <code>columns</code> columns.
     * 
     * @param rows    the amount of rows in the matrix.
     * @param columns the amount of columns in the new matrix.
     */
    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        this.matrix = new double[rows][];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            this.matrix[i] = new double[columns];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a zero square matrix with <code>dimension</code> rows and
     * columns.
     * 
     * @param dimension the dimension of this square matrix.
     */
    public Matrix(int dimension) {
        this(dimension, dimension);
    }

    /**
     * Multiplies this matrix by vertex <code>v</code> and returns the result,
     * which is a vertex too.
     * 
     * @param  v the vertex to multiply by this matrix.
     * @return the result vertex.
     */
    public Vertex product(Vertex v) {
        double[] vector = new double[]{ v.x, v.y, v.z };
        double[] vec = new double[vector.length];

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; ++col) {
                vec[row] += vector[col] * matrix[row][col];
            }
        }

        return new Vertex(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the matrix for rotating around <tt>x</tt>-axis.
     * 
     * @param  angle the rotation angle in radians.
     * @return the rotation matrix.
     */
    public static Matrix getXRotationMatrix(double angle) {
        final Matrix ret = new Matrix(3);

        ret.matrix[0][0] = 1;
        ret.matrix[0][1] = 0;
        ret.matrix[0][2] = 0;
        ret.matrix[1][0] = 0;
        ret.matrix[2][0] = 0;

        ret.matrix[1][1] = Math.cos(angle);
        ret.matrix[1][2] = -Math.sin(angle);
        ret.matrix[2][1] = Math.sin(angle);
        ret.matrix[2][2] = Math.cos(angle);

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the matrix for rotating around <tt>y</tt>-axis.
     * 
     * @param  angle the rotation angle in radians.
     * @return the rotation matrix.
     */
    public static Matrix getYRotationMatrix(double angle) {
        final Matrix ret = new Matrix(3);

        ret.matrix[0][1] = 0;
        ret.matrix[1][0] = 0;
        ret.matrix[1][2] = 0;
        ret.matrix[2][1] = 0;
        ret.matrix[1][1] = 1;

        ret.matrix[0][0] = +Math.cos(angle);
        ret.matrix[0][2] = +Math.sin(angle);
        ret.matrix[2][0] = -Math.sin(angle);
        ret.matrix[2][2] = +Math.cos(angle);

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the matrix for rotating around <tt>z</tt>-axis.
     * 
     * @param  angle the rotation angle in radians.
     * @return the rotation matrix.
     */
    public static Matrix getZRotationMatrix(double angle) {
        final Matrix ret = new Matrix(3);

        ret.matrix[0][2] = 0;
        ret.matrix[1][2] = 0;
        ret.matrix[2][2] = 1;
        ret.matrix[2][1] = 0;
        ret.matrix[2][0] = 0;

        ret.matrix[0][0] =  Math.cos(angle);
        ret.matrix[0][1] = -Math.sin(angle);
        ret.matrix[1][0] =  Math.sin(angle);
        ret.matrix[1][1] =  Math.cos(angle);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Vertex.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.lib3d;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class implements a vertex that can be thought of as a vector.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Vertex implements Iterable<Vertex> {

    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    /**
     * The list of neighbor vertices.
     */
    private final List<Vertex> neighborVertexList;

    /**
     * The list of colors.
     */
    private final List<Color> neighborColorList;

    /**
     * Constructs a new vertex.
     * 
     * @param x the initial <tt>x</tt>-coordinate.
     * @param y the initial <tt>y</tt>-coordinate.
     * @param z the initial <tt>z</tt>-coordinate.
     */
    public Vertex(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.neighborVertexList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.neighborColorList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new vertex with the same coordinates as <code>other</code>.
     * 
     * @param other the other vertex.
     */
    public Vertex(Vertex other) {
        this(other.x, other.y, other.z);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new vertex located at origo.
     */
    public Vertex() {
        this(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the view of colors of this vertex.
     * 
     * @return the color view.
     */
    public List<Color> getColorList() {
        return Collections.<Color>unmodifiableList(neighborColorList);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the view of neighbor vertices of this vertex.
     * 
     * @return the neighbor view.
     */
    public List<Vertex> getNeighborList() {
        return Collections.<Vertex>unmodifiableList(neighborVertexList);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a neighbor vertex to this vertex.
     * 
     * @param neighbor the neighbor to add.
     * @param color    the color of the edge from this vertex to 
     *                 <code>neighbor</code>.
     */
    public void addNeighbor(Vertex neighbor, Color color) {
        neighborVertexList.add(neighbor);
        neighborColorList.add(color);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator over neighbor vertices of this vertex.
     * 
     * @return an iterator.
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<Vertex> iterator() {
        return this.neighborVertexList.iterator();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this vertex.
     * 
     * @return a string.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Vertex (" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ")]";
    }
}
```

**SceneObject.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.lib3d;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class models an object in the scene.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class SceneObject implements Iterable<Vertex> {

    /**
     * The list of vertices this object consists of. These are vector pointing
     * from <code>location</code>.
     */
    private final List<Vertex> vertexList;

    /**
     * The location of this object.
     */
    private final Vertex location;

    /**
     * Constructs a new scene object with given location.
     * 
     * @param x the <tt>x</tt>-coordinate of the location.
     * @param y the <tt>y</tt>-coordinate of the location.
     * @param z the <tt>z</tt>-coordinate of the location.
     */
    public SceneObject(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.location = new Vertex(x, y, z);
        this.vertexList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new scene object with given location.
     * 
     * @param vertex the initial location.
     */
    public SceneObject(Vertex vertex) {
        this(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.y);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new scene object with location at origo.
     */
    public SceneObject() {
        this(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the view of vertices belonging to this object.
     * 
     * @return the vertex view.
     */
    public List<Vertex> getVertexList() {
        return Collections.<Vertex>unmodifiableList(vertexList);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the location of this scene object.
     * 
     * @return the location.
     */
    public Vertex getLocation() {
        return new Vertex(location);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the location of this object.
     * 
     * @param  v the new location.
     */
    public void setLocation(Vertex v) {
        this.location.x = v.x;
        this.location.y = v.y;
        this.location.z = v.z;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a vertex to this object.
     * 
     * @param vertex the vertex to add.
     */
    public void add(Vertex vertex) {
        this.vertexList.add(vertex);
    }

    /**
     * Rotates this geometric object relative to the point
     * <code>relative</code>.
     *
     * @param relative the relative point.
     * @param angleAroundX the angle around the <tt>x</tt>-axis.
     * @param angleAroundY the angle around the <tt>y</tt>-axis.
     * @param angleAroundZ the angle around the <tt>z</tt>-axis.
     */
    public void rotate(Vertex relative,
                       double angleAroundX,
                       double angleAroundY,
                       double angleAroundZ) {
        rotateImpl(relative,
                   location,
                   angleAroundX,
                   angleAroundY,
                   angleAroundZ);

        // Rotate the locatio vector of this geometric object.
        final Vertex zero = new Vertex();

        // Rotate the vertex vectors.
        for (final Vertex vertex : vertexList) {
            rotateImpl(zero,
                       vertex,
                       -angleAroundX,
                       -angleAroundY,
                       -angleAroundZ);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implements the rotation routine.
     *
     * @param relative the relative location.
     * @param target the vertex to rotate.
     * @param angleAroundXAxis the angle around the <tt>x</tt>-axis.
     * @param angleAroundY the angle around the <tt>y</tt>-axis.
     * @param angleAroundZ the angle around the <tt>z</tt>-axis.
     */
    private void rotateImpl(Vertex relative,
                            Vertex target,
                            double angleAroundXAxis,
                            double angleAroundYAxis,
                            double angleAroundZAxis) {
        final Matrix x = Matrix.getXRotationMatrix(angleAroundXAxis);
        final Matrix y = Matrix.getYRotationMatrix(angleAroundYAxis);
        final Matrix z = Matrix.getZRotationMatrix(angleAroundZAxis);

        Vertex tmp = new Vertex(target.x - relative.x,
                                target.y - relative.y,
                                target.z - relative.z);

        tmp = x.product(tmp);
        tmp = y.product(tmp);
        tmp = z.product(tmp);

        target.x = relative.x + tmp.x;
        target.y = relative.y + tmp.y;
        target.z = relative.z + tmp.z;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Vertex> iterator() {
        return this.vertexList.iterator();
    }
}
```

**SceneView.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.lib3d;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class implements a scene view displaying three-dimensional objects.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 */
public class SceneView extends Canvas implements KeyListener {

    /**
     * The list of scene objects in this view.
     */
    private final List<SceneObject> sceneObjectList;

    /**
     * The rotation source. All objects are rotated with respect to this point.
     */
    private final Vertex rotationSource;

    /**
     * Constructs this scene canvas.
     *
     * @param width the width of this canvas in pixels.
     * @param height the height of this canvas in pixels.
     */
    public SceneView(int width, 
                     int height) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.sceneObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.rotationSource = new Vertex(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    /**
     * Draws this view.
     * 
     * @param g the graphics device handle.
     */
    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        for (final SceneObject object : sceneObjectList) {
            final Vertex objectOrigin = object.getLocation();
            final List<Vertex> vertexList = object.getVertexList();

            for (int i = 0; i < vertexList.size(); ++i) {
                final Vertex v = vertexList.get(i);
                final List<Color> colorList = v.getColorList();
                final List<Vertex> neighborList = v.getNeighborList();

                for (int j = 0; j < neighborList.size(); ++j) {
                    final Vertex neighbor = neighborList.get(j);

                    g.setColor(colorList.get(j));

                    g.drawLine((int) Math.round(objectOrigin.x + v.x),
                               (int) Math.round(objectOrigin.y + v.y),
                               (int) Math.round(objectOrigin.x + neighbor.x),
                               (int) Math.round(objectOrigin.y + neighbor.y));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draws this view.
     * 
     * @param g the graphics device handle.
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        update(g);
    }

    /**
     * Adds all the vectors in <code>vectors</code> to this scene view.
     *
     * @param objects the world objects to add to this view.
     */
    public void addWorldObject(SceneObject... objects) {
        sceneObjectList.addAll(Arrays.asList(objects));
    }

    /**
     * Responds to the event of a key being typed.
     * 
     * @param e the key event.
     */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getExtendedKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:

                sceneObjectList.stream().forEach((o) -> {
                    o.rotate(rotationSource, 0.0, -0.1, 0.0);
                });
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_D:

                sceneObjectList.stream().forEach((o) -> {
                    o.rotate(rotationSource, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0);
                });
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_W:

                sceneObjectList.stream().forEach((o) -> {
                    o.rotate(rotationSource, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
                });
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_S:

                sceneObjectList.stream().forEach((o) -> {
                    o.rotate(rotationSource, -0.1, -0.0, 0.0);
                });
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_Q:

                sceneObjectList.stream().forEach((o) -> {
                    o.rotate(rotationSource, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1);
                });
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_E:

                sceneObjectList.stream().forEach((o) -> {
                    o.rotate(rotationSource, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
                });
                break;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

**SceneFrame.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.lib3d;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * This class implements the frame containing a view.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class SceneFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * The actual view component.
     */
    private final SceneView view;

    /**
     * Constructs a frame containing the view.
     * 
     * @param width  the width of the frame in pixels.
     * @param height the height of the frame in pixels.
     */
    SceneFrame(int width, int height) {
        super("3D Cube");
        add(view = new SceneView(width, height));
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Dimension screenDimension = 
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // Center out the frame.
        setLocation((screenDimension.width - getWidth()) / 2,
                    (screenDimension.height - getHeight()) / 2);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the scene view.
     * 
     * @return the scene view.
     */
    public SceneView getSceneView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.lib3d;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo {

    /**
     * The entry point into a program.

     * @param args the command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { 
            SceneFrame frame = new SceneFrame(600, 600);

            // Let's build a wire cube.
            SceneObject cube = new SceneObject(300, 300, 0);

            // The vertices.
            Vertex v000 = new Vertex(-100, -100, -100);
            Vertex v001 = new Vertex(-100, -100, 100);
            Vertex v010 = new Vertex(-100, 100, -100);
            Vertex v011 = new Vertex(-100, 100, 100);

            Vertex v100 = new Vertex(100, -100, -100);
            Vertex v101 = new Vertex(100, -100, 100);
            Vertex v110 = new Vertex(100, 100, -100);
            Vertex v111 = new Vertex(100, 100, 100);

            Color red = Color.red;
            Color green = Color.green;
            Color yellow = Color.yellow;

            // Each vertex must know what other vertices it is linked to.
            v000.addNeighbor(v001, red);
            v000.addNeighbor(v010, red);
            v000.addNeighbor(v100, yellow);

            v001.addNeighbor(v101, yellow);
            v001.addNeighbor(v011, red);
            v001.addNeighbor(v000, red);

            v010.addNeighbor(v110, yellow);
            v010.addNeighbor(v000, red);
            v010.addNeighbor(v011, red);

            v011.addNeighbor(v111, yellow);
            v011.addNeighbor(v001, red);
            v011.addNeighbor(v010, red);

            //

            v100.addNeighbor(v000, yellow);
            v100.addNeighbor(v110, green);
            v100.addNeighbor(v101, green);

            v101.addNeighbor(v001, yellow);
            v101.addNeighbor(v111, green);
            v101.addNeighbor(v100, green);

            v110.addNeighbor(v010, yellow);
            v110.addNeighbor(v100, green);
            v110.addNeighbor(v111, green);

            v111.addNeighbor(v011, yellow);
            v111.addNeighbor(v101, green);
            v111.addNeighbor(v110, green);

            // Load the vertices to the cube.
            cube.add(v000);
            cube.add(v001);
            cube.add(v010);
            cube.add(v011);

            cube.add(v100);
            cube.add(v101);
            cube.add(v110);
            cube.add(v111);

            cube.rotate(cube.getLocation(), 
                        0.0,
                        Math.PI / 2.0,
                        0.0);

            // Add to the scene.
            frame.getSceneView().addWorldObject(cube);
        });
    }
}
```

Any improvements I could do here?

(For demonstration, click the window and use the keys Q, W, E, A, S, D to rotate the cube.)

Comment: The cube doesn't move for me. I added console output to the keytyped, keyPressed and keyReleased. Only keyPressed and keyReleaed are firing, So i'm not sure what is up yet.

Comment: What OS are you on? Wrote this on MacOSX. Never tried it on other platforms.

Comment: win 7. keytyped is returning 0 for keycode, 0 for extended key code. The only thing correct is the keyChar. I'm looking into it right now

Comment: i bet its because its complaining because "KEY_TYPED (is only generated if a valid Unicode character could be generated.)"

Comment: So does it work if you move entire `switch` under `keyPressed`?

Comment: yes. Wow.. that is cool! Can't wait to code review this :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope that helps some.

Comment: Is this supposed to take in radians? because when I do the math using radians I get the same values as my test expects

Comment: The trigonometric functions `Math.x` treat the input values as radians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll edit this answer again later when I have more time. I have a lot to say. Since I've only had a chance to play with SceneView.java that is what I'm going to mention.

the update method is too large. It needs to get broken up into smaller pieces. Typically I personally like to grab everything inside a loop (be it a while loop, or a for loop) and put it into a new method. With your update method I made 2 more methods: `updateSceneObject` and `updateVertex`. I notice too that you switch back and forth with how you iterate through things. Be consistent. Here is a small look at my solution. **Note that there is a small bug introduced with this method because your current mode of drawing relies on each matrix being drawn at a specific order.**

```
/**
 * Draws this view.
 *
 * @param g the graphics device handle.
 */
@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.red);

    sceneObjectList.parallelStream().forEach(o->updateSceneObject(g,o));
}

private void updateSceneObject(Graphics g, SceneObject object) {
    final Vertex objectOrigin = object.getLocation();
    object.getVertexList().parallelStream().forEach(v->updateVertex(g,objectOrigin, v));
}

private void updateVertex(Graphics g, Vertex objectOrigin, Vertex v) {
    final List<Color> colorList = v.getColorList();
    final List<Vertex> neighborList = v.getNeighborList();

    for (int j = 0; j < neighborList.size(); ++j) {
        final Vertex neighbor = neighborList.get(j);

        g.setColor(colorList.get(j));

        g.drawLine((int) Math.round(objectOrigin.x + v.x),
                (int) Math.round(objectOrigin.y + v.y),
                (int) Math.round(objectOrigin.x + neighbor.x),
                (int) Math.round(objectOrigin.y + neighbor.y));
    }
}
```

**Vertex.java**

having a list of neighbors and their colors (as a parallel list) is 2 parts wrong. 1 reason it is wrong is a parallel list. in other words you an array that depends on a very specific order. Should that order get disturbed some problems can arise. Usually you will want to encapsulate those values in another class and make a single list of those. the second part of why it is wrong is that I believe Vertex should simply be a data structure and nothing more. I can see your reasoning behind it but neighbor doesn't describe well enough that your line segment is a specific color. (Took me a little bit to figure that out) So to fix points one and two I believe if you make a LineSegment class that has 2 vertices and a single color your code will clean up nicely. Then you would just change Cube to have a list of LineSegments and update those when you rotate.

**Tests**

I'm a huge advocate of writing tests. First they act as a form of documentation, then also give you a safety net to change things around with less fear of breaking something. A good thing that should have tests around it is the rotate method for SceneObject. So for instance

```
public class SceneObjectTest {

    @Test
    public void testRotate() throws Exception {
        SceneObject object = new SceneObject(0,0,0);
        final Vertex CENTER = new Vertex(0,0,0);
        Vertex vertex0 = new Vertex(-10, 0, 0);
        Vertex vertex1 = new Vertex(10, 0, 0);

        object.add(vertex0);
        object.add(vertex1);

        object.rotate(CENTER, 1, 0, 0 );//rotate 1 degree on x
        System.out.println(vertex0);
        System.out.println(vertex1);

        assertXYZ(vertex0, -10, 0, 0);//0
        assertXYZ(vertex1, 10, 0, 0);//0
    }

    private void assertXYZ(Vertex vertex, double x, double y, double z) {
        assertEquals(vertex.x, x, String.format("expected Vertex to have x coordinate of %f but found %f\r\nActual:%s", x, vertex.x, vertex));
        assertEquals(vertex.y, y, String.format("expected Vertex to have y coordinate of %f but found %f\r\nActual:%s", y, vertex.y, vertex));
        assertEquals(vertex.z, z, String.format("expected Vertex to have z coordinate of %f but found %f\r\nActual:%s", z, vertex.z, vertex));
    }
}
```

this test takes 0.394 seconds to run and tells me that rotating a horizontal line on the x axis does nothing. Which is correct. So what happens if I rotate 1 degree on the z axis. (Which I can visualize easily in my head) I would expect the following test to pass (look at `testRotateOnZAxis()`)

```
public class SceneObjectTest {

    final Vertex CENTER = new Vertex(0, 0, 0);
    SceneObject object;
    private Vertex vertex0;
    private Vertex vertex1;

    @BeforeTest
    public void SetupBeforeTest() {
        object = new SceneObject(0, 0, 0);
        vertex0 = new Vertex(-10, 0, 0);
        vertex1 = new Vertex(10, 0, 0);

        object.add(vertex0);
        object.add(vertex1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRotateOnXAxis() throws Exception {
        object.rotate(CENTER, 1, 0, 0);//rotate 1 degree on x
        System.out.println(vertex0);
        System.out.println(vertex1);

        assertXYZ(vertex0, -10, 0, 0);//0
        assertXYZ(vertex1, 10, 0, 0);//0
    }

    @Test
    public void testRotateOnZAxis() throws Exception {
        object.rotate(CENTER, 0, 0, 1);//rotate 1 degree on z
        System.out.println(vertex0);
        System.out.println(vertex1);
        //x' = x * cos(1); (-10 * 0.99984769515639123915701155881391), (10 * 0.99984769515639123915701155881391)
        //y' = y * sin(1); (-10 * 0.01745240643728351281941897851632), (10 * 0.01745240643728351281941897851632)
        assertXYZ(vertex0,-9.9984769515639123915701155881391,-0.1745240643728351281941897851632, 0);
        assertXYZ(vertex1, 9.9984769515639123915701155881391, 0.1745240643728351281941897851632, 0);
    }

    private void assertXYZ(Vertex vertex, double x, double y, double z) {
        assertEquals(vertex.x, x, String.format("expected Vertex to have x coordinate of %f but found %f\r\nActual:%s", x, vertex.x, vertex));
        assertEquals(vertex.y, y, String.format("expected Vertex to have y coordinate of %f but found %f\r\nActual:%s", y, vertex.y, vertex));
        assertEquals(vertex.z, z, String.format("expected Vertex to have z coordinate of %f but found %f\r\nActual:%s", z, vertex.z, vertex));
    }
}
```

That test fails

> ```
> [Vertex (-5.403023058681398, 8.414709848078965, 0.0)]
> [Vertex (5.403023058681398, -8.414709848078965, 0.0)]
> java.lang.AssertionError: expected Vertex to have x coordinate of -9.998477 but found -5.403023
> Actual:[Vertex (-5.403023058681398, 8.414709848078965, 0.0)] 
> Expected :-9.998476951563912
> Actual   :-5.403023058681398
> ```

Now it is possible that I'm asserting incorrectly, but that is what the tests do. They show us what you expect to happen given certain circumstances. Hope this helps some.

Comment: LineSegment idea is cool. Accepted.